# Email con PHP no llega al destinatario ¿fallo con el servidor?

Tags: php

La función de php **mail()** devuelve *true* o *false*. Obtengo *true* pero el email no llega al destino y pienso que es por la configuración del servidor. Uso un servidor ***Linux Debian***.

Código:

```
$para .= 'wez@example.com';
$título = 'Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto';
$mensaje = 'Hola';
$cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$cabeceras .= 'To: Mary , Kelly ' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio ' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código que tienes actualmente?

Comment: gracias abajo lo mandé el código está en un servidor linux debian

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta (justo debajo del contenido de la misma tienes el botón de editar) y añade el código allí. No debería de haber información añadida como respuestas. Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: gracias ya lo edité la pregunta

Comment: ¿Tienes un servidor de correo configurado en tu servidor?

Comment: como puedo configurar creo que eso es el problema, te agradesco de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar PHPMailer y tu cuenta de Gmail para enviar correos de esta manera Saludes

```
<?php
//Load 
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;// TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username ='algien@gmail.com'; //tu gmail
$mail->Password = '31542'; //tu password
//Agregar destinatario
$mail->setFrom('user@mail.com', 'Mary , Kelly');
$mail->AddAddress('wez@example.com');//A quien mandar email
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 

    //Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto';
$mail->Body    = 'Hola</b>';


if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Error al enviar email';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Mail enviado correctamente';
}
```